# progress indicator for javafx app

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I'm using below code for showing progress indicator for loading tasks.I'm using MaskerPane from ControlsFX progress indicator.
But when i using the component , maskerpane only showing 1 time..Please suggest a better way for showing progress indicator.

```
@FXML
    private MaskerPane progressPane;
 @FXML
        private void addMemberSelect() {
            Task task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    progressPane.setVisible(true);
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void succeeded(){
                    super.succeeded();
                    content.setContent(null);
                    ScreensController colllectScreenController = new ScreensController();
                    colllectScreenController.loadScreen(Screens.ADD_MEMBER);
                    colllectScreenController.setScreen(Screens.ADD_MEMBER);
                    content.setContent(colllectScreenController);
                    progressPane.setVisible(false);
                }
            };
            new Thread(task).start();
        }
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you want to achieve from the MaskPane? What is not working? What do you mean by, "maskerpane only showing 1 time" ?

Comment: sorry for my English.Actually i want to show progress while switching the scenes.Each scenes contain some db operations .So i want show  progress indicators.The above code i'm using is only showing the progress
once.Next time it wont show any progress bar

Comment: I do not see you updating the progress by using [updateProgress()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateProgress-double-double-) on the task. If you do not use it, the progress indicator will never show progress. There are multiple examples showing on how to use it in the javadocs for [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html).

Comment: Im using MaskerPane's show and hide property.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I my opinion it should have worked. Can you try out [this example](https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/13f8cc637872ebac4385f92cd16075a7) and come back with differences it has wrt your code.

Answer (score 2):

This example can help you.

```
public class MaskerPaneTest extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    MaskerPane progressPane = new MaskerPane();
    progressPane.setVisible(false);

    Button button = new Button("Show");
    button.setOnAction(event -> {

            Task task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    progressPane.setVisible(true);
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void succeeded(){
                    super.succeeded();
                    progressPane.setVisible(false);
                }
            };
            new Thread(task).start();
        });
    VBox box = new VBox(button, progressPane);
    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

}
Source: https://gist.github.com/TheItachiUchiha/13f8cc637872ebac4385f92cd16075a7

I tested it and it works well, so you can adapt it.